# Invalid schema for REST JSON CreatePassengerNameRecord response

Tags: sabre

I am trying to test the integration for the Sabre CreatePassengerNameRecord rest API. As the first step, I tried downloading the JSON schemas for the Request and Response and tried to generate the POJOs using jsonschema2pojo. But it looks like the schema files are all pointing to dependent references using a URL http://services.sabre.com which is non existing. Hence the POJO generation is getting failed. This is happening for both the request and response. I was able to fix the request schema by changing the URL for XMLSchemaTypes.json dependency to provided URL link in documentation, but the response has a reference which is not specified anywhere (Please check the **Response schema** section of question ).

API Link: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/book/create_passenger_name_record/

**Response Schema:**

In the response, there is a reference to http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_02 which is not existing.

File : http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/STPS/create_passenger_name_record/v200/CreatePassengerNameRecord2.0.0RS.json

```
....
"CreatePassengerNameRecordRS" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "title" : "CreatePassengerNameRecordRS",
      "properties" : {
        "version" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "minLength" : 1,
          "maxLength" : 255
        },
        "ApplicationResults" : {
          "$ref" : "http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_02#/definitions/ApplicationResults"
....
```

It would be great it you could provide the latest file for the STL_Payload or update the documentation to the latest working version.

Answer (score 1):

The missing files were added to the documentation page. 
This should allow you to move forward.
The id-s are still used as tags and not as absolute resource pointers so you still need to play with it they way you described to make the auto-generation working out of the box.
We will consider your request to convert them to resource pointers in the future.
Just one more hint: if you are using Java-API version of jsonschema2pojo please use this for config:

```
GenerationConfig config = new DefaultGenerationConfig() {
    public String getRefFragmentPathDelimiters() {
        return "#/";
    }
};
```

You need it because the default path delimiters in jsonschema2pojo are "#/." and the "." does not work with some of the types declared in the schema like Text.Long

Answer (score 0):

+1 Sabre please make JSON schema available on http://services.sabre.com as it is problematic when generating models using Quicktype. Types are not being resolved correctly.